# Add app to share menu ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Is there a way to add my app to the share menu for images and videos on the iPhone? I know there is on the android and I'm curious as to if apple lets me do this too or if they like having complete control as much as I think they do. If there is, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide API for adding third-party services to the Share menus in Photos and other built-in apps.